# Is it possible to quickly swap left/right audio channels for speakers, on demand? (win10)

Tags: windows, audio

I have a need to sometimes switch left/right audio channels.

Reason for this, is that I have TV with speakers right behind me, when I am at my PC. So when I am watching something on TV (via HDMI from PC), and I am facing TV, I need normal left/right setup. However, if I am watching something on PC, I need to swap left/right channel, as speakers are now behind me and reversed (left speaker is on my right now, etc.).

Is it possible to have a shortcut, or a similar easy way to swap channels?

Comment: see https://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/153182-swap-left-right-audio-channels.html